# Remove query strings from url

Tags: php, url, query-string

How do I remove query strings from a url?

Example: I have a url such as the following:

```
http://example.com?q1=v1&q2=v2&q3=v3
```

I want to remove `q1` and `q3`, leave `q2`, and add `q4` with its value `v4`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda depends on if you know what the keys are or not. If you do, it'd be something like this:

```
$params = $_GET;

unset($params['q1']);
unset($params['q3']);

$params['q4'] = 'v4';

$my_new_param_string = http_build_query($params);
$new_url = 'http://example.com?' . $my_new_param_string;
```

You can manipulate $_GET directly, but I don't like to do that personally.
More info on http_build_query:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

If you just have that url as a string, you can do this instead:

```
$url_bits = parse_url('http://example.com/?q1=v1&q2=v2&q3=v3');
$params = parse_str($url_bits['query']);
```

And the rest works the same as the bit after $params = $_GET up above.

You can also use $url_bits to turn it back into a string later if you need to.

Comment: Oh, and I was assuming that you already have those params in the GET. If you don't, you'll need parse_url. I'll add that to the answer.